# Form.Owner - Owned forms not closing/hiding recursively

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx) states:

> When a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the
>   owner form. For example, consider a form named `Form2` that is owned by
>   a form named `Form1`. If `Form1` is closed or minimized, `Form2` is also
>   closed or hidden.

Apparently the hiding isn't working recursively? When I have a stack of 4 forms who are parented to each other (`GrandChildForm.Owner = Child; ChildForm.Owner = ParentForm;` etc.), minimizing any one of them only minimizes it's direct child too.

Similar effect when closing one of these forms, only the FormClosing/Closed events of the direct child are raised, but not for the other accestors. [Again the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) don't state that this doesn't work recursively:

> If a form has any child or owned forms, a `FormClosing` event is also
>   raised for each one. If any one of the forms cancels the event, none
>   of the forms are closed.

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Minimize/restore a form should also minimize/restore all it's ancestors.
- Closing a form should go al the way down the hierarchy of forms to the "youngest" child, if any of them decides not to close (`FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel = true;`) then the deal is off.

Should this be implemented using extra event handling (subscribing to the Owner's `FormClosing`/`FormClosed`/`SizeChanged` events) or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit your form from this class:

```
public class AdvancedForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form f in this.OwnedForms)
        {
            f.Close();
        }

        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);

        foreach (AdvancedForm f in this.OwnedForms)
        {
            switch (this.WindowState)
            {
                case FormWindowState.Minimized:
                case FormWindowState.Normal:
                    f.WindowState = this.WindowState;
                    break;

                case FormWindowState.Maximized:
                    // just restore owned forms to their original sizes when parent form is maximized
                    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                    break;
            }

            // OnSizeChanged must be called, as changing WindowState property
            // does not raise SizeChanged event
            f.OnSizeChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

    }
}
```

Or just use code from this class in "Closing" and "SizeChanged" event handlers.

Comment: I guessed that was the way to go, just wondered if I was missing something since the documentation wasn't clear on that. Thanks!

Comment: A weird side effect of the OnFormClosing code is that the FormClosing event is raised twice every two forms in the hierarchy chain. It appears to me that the logic behind setting Owner (FormClosing is raised for each owned Form) is also being performed (but only for the direct child).

Comment: I have not tested the code, just gave you an idea ;) Maybe removing base.OnFormClosing(e) will help ;)